# Keeping the sqlite 3 database open using swift 3

Tags: xcode, sqlite, swift3, fmdb

I am able to create tables and load several of them with data but when I go to access the data again to retrieve data the program is telling the table does not exist.
I am creating the tables from within the viewcontroller. I read in one of these posts that it should not be done from within viewcontroller but from another class. My question is who should this be done. I would also like to be able to insert and retrieve data from a second viewcontroller.
How is this accomplished? What type of class needs to be set up to keep the database open throughout the entire program? I have searched the internet for answers but have not found what I am looking.
An example and some explanations would be most helpful.
If more information is needed I can provide.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO! How does your `viewcontroller` create the tables, with which code? In which post did you read about where it is supposed to happen? 
Please add the code you are trying to use for every one of your questions. Without code the question is too vague and there are too many different answers for it.

Comment: here is the code I am using.

Comment: Is there a way for me to send you the portion of the code I am using? The code itself is too long to send .

Comment: Creat a gist.github and copy the link. But please copy the main parts to the question by editing it.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/dino624/58dbb786246468e5a04ea2dee2d83d93